# queue up Http.sys queue intentionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, http.sys

I am trying to intentionally cause the http.sys queue to queue up by limiting the maximum number of worker threads to 1 and sending multiple requests to an API that keeps running forever.

I have read multiple articles where I understand that the http.sys deliver the request to an IIS worker process that hands off the request to a cheap CLR thread.

what I understand as well is that we were able to limit the max number or worker  threads and IOCP worker threads by modifying the machine.config. I have set the value to 1 and sent 30 requests to an api that has infit loop but I have not really noticed that the HTTP Service Request Queues/Current Queue Size performance counter has increased, sometimes the ASP.Net v4.0.30319/Requests Queued increases but this is not what I expected, the http.sys queue only queues up when I send hundreds of requests. Below is the configuration I used to set the max worker and IO threads to 1

```
<processModel maxWorkerThreads="1" maxIoThreads="1">
```

**Please note that I am doing local requests, my IIS version it 10.0.14393.0 and using windows server 2016 so not sure if this is related somehow.**

**Screenshot from my machine**
[image]

**References:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/performance-call-web-service#cause
[https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET-2#:~:text=Inside%20the%20ASP.NET%20Worker,and%20databases%2C%20etc.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET-2#:%7E:text=Inside%20the%20ASP.NET%20Worker,and%20databases%2C%20etc.)).
https://blog.leansentry.com/all-about-iis-asp-net-request-queues/

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: There are other queue settings you should dig, https://github.com/lextm/iis_schema/blob/master/IIS_schema.xml

Comment: Hey @LexLi, thanks for the comment, could you please exactly explain what to change?. I have done a little bit more research and I found that under the ASP feature in IIS you can set the Threads Per Processor Limit  which is by default 25, I have set it to 1 and started seeing requests queuing up and after few seconds they were handed to the CLR threads, so it this limit equivalent to the configuration I am trying to do  

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/optimizing-iis-performance#tune-the-value-of-the-asp-threads-per-processor-limit-property

Comment: and one more question, why the requests where handed of to the CLR where the one worker thread was still busy waiting for a response for the first request

Comment: You only need to search for "queue" in IIS_schema.xml and then study what most of them mean from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/ Don't waste your time on ASP or FastCGI as they simply don't apply.